# How to make a HTTP request behalf another session in a Laravel test?

Tags: php, laravel, testing

When I perform HTTP tests in Laravel 5 using [built-in tools](https://laravel.com/docs/http-tests), the framework remembers the session data from request to request.

```
class HttpTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        // Suppose this endpoint creates a session and adds some data to it
        $this->get('/action/fillSession');

        // Suppose this endpoint reads the session data
        $this->get('/action/readSession'); // The session data from the first request is available here
    }
}
```

How to perform a request with another session between the requests above without destroying the original first session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember the first session data, flush the application session, make the "another session" request and return the original session data back to the application:

```
class HttpTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        // Suppose this endpoint creates a session and adds some data to it
        $this->get('/action/fillSession');

        $session = $this->app['session']->all();
        $this->flushSession();
        $this->get('/noSessionHere');
        $this->flushSession();
        $this->session($session);

        // Suppose this endpoint reads the session data
        $this->get('/action/readSession'); // The session data from the first request is available here
    }
}
```

---

You can carry out this algorithm to a separate method to reuse it easily:

```
class HttpTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testApplication()
    {
        // Suppose this endpoint creates a session and adds some data to it
        $this->get('/action/fillSession');

        $this->asAnotherSession(function () {
            $this->get('/noSessionHere');
        });

        // Suppose this endpoint reads the session data
        $this->get('/action/readSession'); // The session data from the first request is available here
    }

    protected function asAnotherSession(callable $action)
    {
        $session = $this->app['session']->all();
        $this->flushSession();

        $action();

        $this->flushSession();
        $this->session($session);
    }
}
```